# VBA moves worksheet when finished

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running a simple copy/paste script in Excel, but when the code has executed and I turn screen updating back on, the spreadsheet moves to a different worksheet.

In the code below, once the script has been run (by pressing a button on the control page), and after the message box, the spreadsheet moves to the output tab. I've then tried doing some arbitrary copy/paste on the control page as a final operation, but still having the same issue. Is there a way to force the script to move me back to the control page?

```
Sub Outputs()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws0 As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws0 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Control")
Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Output")

ws1.Range("Data_Copy").Copy
ws2.Range("Data_Paste").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

MsgBox "Finished"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: [PasteSpetial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.pastespecial) may change the sheet selection. You will need to reselect the previous sheet manually with  ws0.activate

Comment: What does "the spreadsheet moves to a different worksheet." mean though...

Comment: simple as that! ws0.activate worked. @JNevill - what I meant was that as the user, you are on the 'Control' tab and then click the macro button. It runs the Outputs() macro and then when finished, the user is left looking at the outputs tab (no longer on the control tab).

Comment: @user3722815 That makes sense and I understand now what the question was and why the answer was suggested. Kudos to VincentG for reading between the lines there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to activate back the "Control" worksheet with:

```
ws0.Activate
```